# unable to create application using play-mailer

Tags: playframework-2.6

I am trying to integrate `play-mailer` in my application - https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer#usage

I am using compile time injection.

So far, in my custom app loader, I have mixed `MailerComponents` trait (https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer/blob/master/play-mailer/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/mailer/MailerComponents.scala).

The configuration in `application.conf` is

```
play.mailer {
  host = localhost // (mandatory)
  port = 25 // (defaults to 25)
  ssl = no // (defaults to no)
  tls = no // (defaults to no)
  tlsRequired = no // (defaults to no)
  user = Administrator // (optional) //TODOM - am I suppose to enter the password here?
  password = codinngjedi // (optional)
  debug = no // (defaults to no, to take effect you also need to set the log level to "DEBUG" for the application logger)
  timeout = null // (defaults to 60s in milliseconds)
  connectiontimeout = null // (defaults to 60s in milliseconds)
  mock = true// (defaults to no, will only log all the email properties instead of sending an email)
}
```

I have created a `MailerService` as follows:

```
package services

import play.api.libs.mailer._

class MailerService(mailerClient: MailerClient) {
  def sendEmail = {
    val email = Email("Simple email", "Mister FROM <from@email.com>", Seq("Miss TO <to@email.com>"), bodyText = Some("A text message"))
    mailerClient.send(email)
  }

}
```

In my custom `AppLoader`, I have created an instance of the `MailerService` as follows:

```
val mailerService = new MailerService(mailerClient) //mailerClient is defined in MailerComponents of play-mailer library
```

My code isn't compiling because I need to provide definition of `config` required by `MailerComponents`

```
trait MailerComponents {
  def config: Config
  lazy val mailerClient: SMTPMailer = new SMTPMailer(new SMTPConfigurationProvider(config).get())
}
```

But I don't know how to do this. The `play-mailer` documentation says that `By default the Mailer Plugin will automatically configure the injected instance with the application.conf.` So why do I need to provide `config` and how do I create it?

Answer (score 0):

I could define `config` as

```
import com.typesafe.config.{Config, ConfigFactory}
def config:Config = {
    val loadedConfig = ConfigFactory.load() //I suppose play looks for application.conf by default
    println("loaded config is "+loadedConfig)
    loadedConfig
  }
```